# powerdesigner how to generate sql using `backquote`

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5, powerdesigner

> Sybase PowerDesigner Version 16.0.0.3514
>   Current DBMS mysql 5.0

Generate SQL

[image]

In fact, I want to add backquote around the field `name`, like this

[image]

---

How to configure it?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Why do you want to add quotes?

Comment: The field name and reserved word repeatedly conflict

Comment: The list of known reserved words is in `Script\Sql\Keywords\ReservedWord`. If you enhance the list, the reserved words should be automatically quoted when used as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the reason to add quotes is to preserve case-sensitivity (not sure whether MySQL supports it)...

- create your own copy of the MySQL DBMS,
- add an item `CaseSensitivityUsingQuote` under `Script > Sql > Format` (`Add
  items...` in the contextual menu on Format),
- set it to Yes.

Comment: Thank you ! 
but , It's useless for DBMS mysql 5.0